# Как организовать получение информации из внешних API в laravel?

Tags: laravel, api

Допустим, я хочу отображать погоду для определенных городов.
Данные буду получать из внешних API и выводить на определенной странице без сохранения в базу данных.

Прописываю `route` к методу контроллера.

Лучше, наверно, обращение к API вынести в отдельный класс и вызывать из контроллера?
Из этого класса отправлять запросы через `guzzle` к API?

Как лучше реализовать, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Лучше наверно обращение к API вынести в отдельный класс и вызывать из
>   контроллера?

Архитектурно вы можете вынести обращение к API в модель, например, `Weather`, у которой будет реализован метод получения данных из внешнего API. Так вы сможете обращаться к этим данным, как будто данные хранятся у вас в БД.

Очевидное улучшение, которое вы можете сделать при таком "проксировании" — это кешировать на разумное время данные о погоде в городе, чтобы при последующих запросах пользователь не видел задержку, которая будет существенной при обращении к внешнему серверу. Ключом кеша может являться `id` города.